# Descrypt only some files with git-crypt unlock and not the entire repo

Tags: git, security, encryption, version-control, git-crypt

I am performing a sparse checkout on a `git` dir that uses `git-crypt`.

A normal `git clone` followed by a `git-crypt unlock` works.

Since I am running a `sparse` checkout, I would also like to perform a partial `git-crypt unlock`

After running

```
g sparse-checkout init
g sparse-checkout add <dir1>
g checkout master
g sparse-checkout add <dir2>
g checkout master
```

NOTE: `g sparse checkout <dir1> <dir2` followed by `g checkout master` **does not work** as it seems to fetch only `<dir2`>

I run `git-crypt unlock`

This however fails miserably since it spits out a ton of errors as in

```
error: pathspec 'path/to/some/other/encrypted/file/not/included/in/my/sparse/checkout' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Any suggestions how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this.
Something that can be done about it is using multiple keys from git crypt, a key for each sparse checkout and another key for the overall encryption.
Docs: https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt/blob/master/doc/multiple_keys.md
Alternative solution and source of my information: https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt/issues/155
The best solution is using multiple keys at the moment.